# Zebra Link-OS Android SDK Multi-channel connection

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I'm having an issue with using ConnectionBuilder class in the Zebra SDK with the BT_MULTI Connection type. I've been told by Zebra reps that this is a known bug and they don't have an ETA on a fix.

The code I use to connect to the printer is as follows:

```
    if (isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        // Make sure we still aren't connected to a printer
        if (thePrinterConnection != null &&
                thePrinterConnection.isConnected()) {
            thePrinterConnection.close();
        }

        // Connect to the printer
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Creating printer connection");

        /* TODO: This should be how the printer is connected to check status when printing,
         * TODO:  but currently throws ConnectionException with "Invalid connection type".
          */
        //thePrinterConnection = ConnectionBuilder.build("BT_MULTI:" + macAddress);
        thePrinterConnection = ConnectionBuilder.build("BT:" + macAddress);

        // Open the connection
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Opening connection");
        thePrinterConnection.open();

        // Get instance of link os printer
        thePrinterInstance = ZebraPrinterFactory.getLinkOsPrinter(thePrinterConnection);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

The commented out line is the currently failing call with the BT_MULTI tag.

Each time I print, I use the asynchronous write() method from the Connection class. To check that the printer is ready for the next print, I make sure the printer is ready by executing this method:

```
public boolean isPrinterReady() {
    /**
     * FIXME: If the printer is receiving data while this is called,
     * FIXME: it throws an exception, even if not printing. Above code might work with blocked
     * FIXME: channel, but currently will not connect to printer.
     */

    // Make sure we have a connection
    if (thePrinterConnection != null && thePrinterInstance != null) {
        try {
            // Try to get current printer status
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Printer is ready: " + thePrinterInstance.getCurrentStatus().isReadyToPrint);
            return thePrinterInstance.getCurrentStatus().isReadyToPrint;
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Error getting printer status", e);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Printer connection was null");
        return false;
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments above, when the printer is in the middle of a write() call and I call the getCurrentStatus() method, it locks up the printer. After that, it will not return status (throws a malformed status exception) and will not continue printing. The printer needs to be power-cycled for it to function again.

Anybody have any suggestions of alternatives?

Thanks!